# Facebook android, get application stream - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm currently working with [Facebook official SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

I'm playing around with the advanced example app right now and I don't see how to make it get the applications wall/stream/status instead of the user that logged in.

Is this possible and how in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/2439131959/feed` gives you Graffiti app wall feed in JSON format. Obviously you have to change 2439131959 with you app id.